# Browser http port-forwarding

Tags: browser, http, port-forwarding

When using a browser like Firefox I need that any url of the domain example.com to have appended the port :8008. Not only when I type it at address bar but any where it is referenced within the served html page. All the other domains should be left as is.

I know I can setup a proxy like Squid or use a pac file in a web site but I want it simpler if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using a **local** pac file (no need for a server):

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) { 
   if (shExpMatch(host, "*example.com")) {
      return "PROXY " + host + ":8008";
   }
   return "DIRECT"; 
}
```

I saved the file as /home/username/local.pac (it is a Linux system). I think it can be named anything. Then in Firefox I went to Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Network -> Settings -> Automactic proxy configuration URL and entered the address as file:///home/username/local.pac. Note the 3 slashes after "file:"

Comment: can you give more detail?  where does this pac file go? does it need to be called anything special (like *foo.pac*)?